# En C++ 11 tengo un problema utilizando interfaces. error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass(Observee (&)())’

Tags: c++, observable

Estoy programando un listener(Observer) en C++ versión 11 y si hago un proyecto nuevo no tengo problemas haciendo unas clases sencillas. Pero cuando incorporo estas clases en mi proyecto principal me da unos errores que no como solucionar.

He probado a hacer los ejemplos que pone la gente en internet, y los he simplificado al máximo posible.

Mi entorno es linux mint y de IDE netbeans con g++

Os el código y el error a ver si podéis ayudarme.

### main.cpp

```
#include "Observer.h"
#include "Observee.h"
#include "Myclass.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Observee observable();
    // AQUI es donde me da el error. he intentado pasarlo con * y con &.
    MyClass obj = new MyClass(observable);
    MyClass obj2(observable);
    observable.Trigger();
```

### Error

```
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
src/main.cpp:64:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass(Observee (&)())’
    MyClass obj = new MyClass(observable);
                                        ^
In file included from src/main.cpp:39:0:
src/Myclass.h:26:8: note: candidate: MyClass::MyClass(Observee&)
        MyClass(Observee& observable1): observable(observable1) {
        ^
src/Myclass.h:26:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Observee()’ to ‘Observee&’
src/Myclass.h:21:7: note: candidate: MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)
class MyClass : public Observer {
    ^
src/Myclass.h:21:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Observee()’ to ‘const MyClass&’
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:123: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'build/Debug/GNU-Linux/src/main.o'
```

### Observer.h

```
#include "Observee.h"

class Observer {
public:
    virtual void Notify()=0;
//    virtual void Notify(Observee* observee)=0;
};
```

### Observee.h

```
class Observer;

class Observee {
public:
    virtual ~Observee();
    bool AddObserver(Observer& observer);
    bool RemoveObserver(Observer& observer);
    bool NotifyObservers();
    void Trigger();
// protected:
    Observee(){};
private:
    std::set<Observer*> observers;
    // Observee(const Observee& orig);
    // Observee& operator=(const Observee& yRef);
};
```

### Observee.cpp

```
#include "Observee.h"
#include "Observer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <set>


Observee::~Observee() {
}

bool Observee::AddObserver( Observer& observer )
{
    if(observers.find(&observer) != observers.end())
        return false;
    observers.insert(&observer);
    return true;
}

//This method removes an observer from the vector
bool Observee::RemoveObserver( Observer& observer )
{
    if(observers.find(&observer) == observers.end())
        return false;
    return observers.erase(&observer) == 1;
}

//This Method is very important, it triggers all Notify() methods of all observers.
//The specific code in each class that inherits from observer will be executed
bool Observee::NotifyObservers()
{
    std::set<Observer*>::iterator itr;
    for ( itr = observers.begin();
        itr != observers.end(); itr++ )
    (*itr)->Notify();
    return (observers.size() > 0);
}

void Observee::Trigger()
{
    NotifyObservers();
}
```

### MyClass.h

```
#include "Observer.h"
#include "Observee.h"
#include <iostream>

class MyClass : public Observer {

        Observee observable;

    public:
    MyClass(Observee& observable1): observable(observable1) {
        observable.AddObserver(*this);
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        observable.RemoveObserver(*this);
    }

    void Notify() {
            std::cout << "Received a change event" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con esta línea

```
Observee observable();
```

Estás declarando una función (aunque a ti te parezca lo contrario y muestra de ello es el mensaje de error:

```
src/main.cpp:64:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass(Observee (&)())’
MyClass obj = new MyClass(observable);
```

Donde `Observee (&)()` es una referencia a una función.

Para llamar al constructor por defecto evita los paréntesis:

```
Observee observable;
```

O, como estás en c++11, también  puedes usar las llaves:

```
Observee observable{};
```

Por otro lado nota que aqui:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(observable);
```

`obj` no es un puntero,  luego no debes usar `new` para instanciarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. He cambiado mi código para que funcione de la siguiente manera.
    Observee observable{};
    MyClass obj(&observable);
    MyClass obj2(&observable);
    observable.Trigger();  

Myclass.h
---------
            Observee *observable;
        public:
           MyClass(Observee* observable1): observable(observable1) {
              observable->AddObserver(*this);
           }

Answer (score 3):

Aquí:

```
Observee observable();
```

No estás creando un objeto sino que estás declarando una función de nombre "observable" que no toma parámetros y que devuelve un objeto de tipo Observee.

Es los que Scott Meyers llamó hace años "most vexing parse", diciendo (lo que yo traduzco como) "Si algo puede ser la declaración de una función, así será". Puedes ver https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Comment: ¡Bien visto! La solución es utilizar inicialización uniforme: `Observee observable{};` o no añadiendo paréntesis: `Observee observable;`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Tu respuesta es tan válida como la otra. He marcado la otra como mejor, por me lo aclara rápidamente. pero tu enlace es magnifico que entender el problema.